# Django success url

Tags: python, django

Прописываю в `success_url` путь `success_url = 'main/index.html'`

Однако выдает ошибку, что путь не найден:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in caparol_center_spb_decision.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
decision/
The current path, main/index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

**Хотя он есть в папке templates/main/index.html**

views:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    form_class = EmailForm
    success_url = 'main/index.html'
    success_message = "Письмо успешно отправлено"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        send_mail('Caparol_Center_Spb',
                  'Теперь вы будете получать лучшие предложения шоу-рума',
                  email,
                  [email, ],
                  fail_silently=False,)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse('Unsuccess')
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ContactView

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ContactView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Comment: мне казалось так нагляднее, но ок заменил

Comment: Мало иметь шаблон в папке, нужно иметь представление, которое этот шаблон будет рендерить, и url-паттерн, к которому представление будет привязана.

Comment: я вставил views и urls все равно не понимаю в чем ошибка

Comment: В приведённом вами urls.py есть только один паттерн, которому соответствует URL `/`. URL'у `main/index.html` он не соответствует.

Comment: все исправил спасибо) сделал через return redirect(reverse('main:index'))

Answer (score 0):

В `success_url` нужно вписывать не путь к HTML-файлу, а сам URL-адрес.

Думаю, в вашем случае файл main.html отвечает за URL-адрес `"/"`, то есть вам нужно прописать следующее: `success_url = "/"`.